# django admin - export as csv

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using the following Django Snippet to export the results of the admin change_list page to csv http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/790/

I have this working but currently I can only get it to export the fields which are defined in the `list_display` variable.

The function accepts a list (named as `fields`, see below) as a variable which defines which fields you want to export but I can't work out how to pass this into the function.  This is because the function is called using the url pattern which does not include a fields variable.

```
def admin_list_export(request, model_name, app_label, queryset=None, fields=None, list_display=True):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to [pass parameters to the function in the url definition](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions):

```
(r'^admin/(?P<app_label>[\d\w]+)/(?P<model_name>[\d\w]+)/csv/',\    
 'util.csv_view.admin_list_export', {'fields': ['myfield1', 'myfield2']}),
```

You can also pass `list_display = False` to the function and it will ignore the `list_display` setting on your ModelAdmin and use all fields the model has!